# How to make root navigation bar transparent, but child navigation bars not?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have been looking around on Stack for some guidance on this, but none of the questions have been asked in this depth nor are the answers updated to the latest swift version, or even work on the newest swift version.

Here's what I have:

- A navigation controller with two bar items:

  - A left button that segues to a view
  - A right button that segues to a view

**My goal:** To make the navigation root view controller's navigation bar transparent (*But have buttons and title still visible*), but not the child navigation - *without* weird nuances, like having the previous color flash, or a cut off nav bar (see gif)

**Things I've tried:**

On the `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` function, make it transparent, then upon `viewWillDisappear()` function, undo it.

Here is my code:

```
     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            print("Will appear")
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        }

        override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        }
```

**This doesn't work.**: What this does is it makes the root view controller's nav bar transparent, but then when I segue to another view controller from a bar item, it flashes the original color and then goes back to clear upon loading of the other view.

I also tried one of the suggestions below (from Md):

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }


        override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        }
```

Here is the **output**: https://giphy.com/gifs/Bcu1Q6qUSV4jPhWo4P

What are some solutions to this? Or ideas to get around this?

Will update question with more info if needed.

Thanks all!

Comment: Have you tried alpha `0.5` on the root level view and `2.0` on child level views?

Answer (score 0):

This code will make  the root navigation bar transparent, but child navigation bars not-

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }

     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
 self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
                self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }


            override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
                self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
                self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

            }
```

Output -
RootNavigation Bar -

[image]

Child Navigation Bar -

[image]

Comment: I'll post a update on how that worked - it did but it was a bit odd. Thanks for the response! Works, but I'll show you what it did.

Comment: But your problem (mentioned in your code) does not appears here right?

Comment: You're right. It did work! But, not EXACTLY what I had in mind. I posted a GIF with a related problem. Thanks Md!

Comment: When you get back from child to root you see the previous color a little bit that because of the animation effect

Comment: Do you know if there’s any way to override this? Or do you think a better option would just be to separate the navigation into separate controllers for what I’m going for?

Comment: better choice will be use separate controller. then you can use segue or can do it programatically..your wish...